# SQL - Sorting Rank by Year

Tags: sql-server

I have a `SELECT` statement which takes reviews and ranks items depending on the review average rating. I used `DENSE_RANK()` and it works properly, it ranks them descending. I want to improve the statement by separating it by year, so the 2016 Ranks go to 1,2,3,4 etc and when it turns to 2017, it restarts again from 1.

```
SELECT 
    PRHYear AS 'Year',
    C.CategoryName AS 'Category',
    M.ManufacturerName AS 'Manufacturer',
    P.ProductName AS 'Product',
    PRHAverageRating AS 'Average Rating',
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY PRHAverageRating DESC) AS 'Rank'
FROM 
    ProductRankingHistory PRH
RIGHT JOIN
    Category C ON PRH.PRHCategory = C.CategoryID
RIGHT JOIN
    Manufacturer M ON PRH.PRHManufacturer = M.ManufacturerID
LEFT JOIN
    Product P ON PRH.PRHProduct = P.ProductID
ORDER BY 
    PRH.PRHYear ASC, PRH.PRHAverageRating DESC
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7M0mn.png)

Comment: hard to figure out without data but ... try changing your Rank Column (line 7) to this and let me know if that works:  DENSE_RANK() OVER (Partition by PRHYear ORDER BY PRHAverageRating DESC) AS 'Rank'

Comment: That works thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Partition by PRHYear to your dense rank evaluation and that will automatically reset the ranks as the Year changes.

See here for more : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql

`SELECT 
    PRHYear AS 'Year',
    C.CategoryName AS 'Category',
    M.ManufacturerName AS 'Manufacturer',
    P.ProductName AS 'Product',
    PRHAverageRating AS 'Average Rating',
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (Partition by PRHYear ORDER BY PRHAverageRating DESC) AS 'Rank'
FROM 
    ProductRankingHistory PRH
RIGHT JOIN
    Category C ON PRH.PRHCategory = C.CategoryID
RIGHT JOIN
    Manufacturer M ON PRH.PRHManufacturer = M.ManufacturerID
LEFT JOIN
    Product P ON PRH.PRHProduct = P.ProductID
ORDER BY 
    PRH.PRHYear ASC, PRH.PRHAverageRating DESC`